# Como listar y crear registros con una relación de muchos a muchos

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

tengo un controlador ingresos donde listo y creo los registros por medio de Query Builder y me funciona. Pero Ahora quiero poder hacerlo con Eloquent y si es posible combinar eloquent con Query Builder.

Este es el codigo de lo que hize con Query Builder:

Modelo Ingreso

```
class Ingreso extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'ingreso';

    protected $primaryKey = 'idingreso';

    public $timestamps=false;

    protected $fillable =[
    'idproveedor',
    'tipo_comprobante',
    'serie_comprobante',
    'numero_comprobante',
    'fecha_hora',
    'impuesto',
    'estado',
    'anticipo'

    ];
}
```

Modelo Detalle Ingreso

```
class DetalledeIngreso extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'detalle_ingreso';

    protected $primaryKey = 'iddetalle_ingreso';

    public $timestamps=false;

    protected $fillable =[
    'idingreso',
    'idarticulo',
    'cantidad',
    'precio_compra',
    'precio_venta'
    ];
}
```

Request IngresoFormRequest

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
    'idarticulo'=>'required',
    'cantidad'=>'required',
    'precio_compra'=>'required',
    'precio_venta'=>'required',
    'idproveedor'=>'required',
    'tipo_comprobante'=>'required|max:20',
    'serie_comprobante' =>'required|max:12',
    'numero_comprobante' =>'required|max:10',
    'anticipo' =>'required'
        ];
    }
```

Listar registros IngresoController@index

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if($request)
        {
            $query=trim($request->GET('searchText'));    
            $ingreso=DB::table('ingreso as i')
            ->join('persona as p','i.idproveedor','=','p.idpersona')
            ->join('detalle_ingreso as di','i.idingreso','=','di.idingreso')
          ->select(
                   'i.idingreso',
                   'i.fecha_hora',
                   'p.nombre',
                   'i.tipo_comprobante',
                   'i.serie_comprobante',
                   'i.numero_comprobante',
                   'i.impuesto',
                   'i.estado',
                   DB::raw('sum(di.cantidad*precio_compra) as total'))
            ->where('i.numero_comprobante','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
            ->orderBy('i.idingreso','desc')
            ->groupBy(
                      'i.idingreso',
                      'i.fecha_hora',
                      'p.nombre',
                      'i.tipo_comprobante',
                      'i.serie_comprobante',
                      'i.numero_comprobante',
                      'i.impuesto',
                      'i.estado')
            ->paginate(7);
            return view('compras.ingreso.index',["ingreso"=>$ingreso,"searchText"=>$query]);
        }
    }
```

Crear registros IngresoController@store

```
public function store(IngresoFormRequest $request)
        {
            try{
                DB::beginTransaction();
                $ingreso=new ingreso();
                $ingreso->idproveedor=$request->get('idproveedor');
                $ingreso->tipo_comprobante=$request->get('tipo_comprobante');
                $ingreso->serie_comprobante=$request->get('serie_comprobante');
                $ingreso->numero_comprobante=$request->get('numero_comprobante');
                $mytime = Carbon::now('America/Bogota');
                $ingreso->fecha_hora=$mytime->toDateTimeString();
                //$ingreso->impuesto='16';//$request->get('impuesto');//16%
                $ingreso->impuesto=(float)$request->get('impuesto');//16%
                $ingreso->estado='A';
                $ingreso->anticipo=$request->get('anticipo');
                $ingreso->save();

                $idarticulo=$request->get('idarticulo');
                $cantidad=$request->get('cantidad');
                $precio_compra=$request->get('precio_compra');
                $precio_venta=$request->get('precio_venta');

                $cont=0;
                While($cont < count($idarticulo)){
                    $detalles=new DetalledeIngreso();
                    $detalles->idingreso=$ingreso->idingreso;
                    $detalles->idarticulo=$idarticulo[$cont];
                    $detalles ->cantidad=$cantidad[$cont];
                    $detalles ->precio_compra=$precio_compra[$cont];
                    $detalles->precio_venta=$precio_venta[$cont];
                    $detalles->save();
                    $cont=$cont+1;
                }
                DB::commit();
            }
    catch(\Exception $e)
    {

            DB::rollback();
        }
          return Redirect::to('compras/ingreso');
        }
```

Vista Index

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Fecha</th>
        <th>Proveedor</th>
        <th>Comprobante</th>
        <th>Impuesto</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
        <th>Opcciones</th>
    </thead>
    @foreach($ingreso as $ing)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$ing->fecha_hora}}</td>
        <td>{{$ing->nombre}}</td>
        <td>{{$ing->tipo_comprobante.': '.$ing->serie_comprobante.'-'.$ing->numero_comprobante}}</td>
        <td>{{$ing->impuesto}}</td>
        <td>{{$ing->total}}</td>
        <td>{{$ing->estado}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{URL::action('IngresoController@show',$ing->idingreso)}}"><button class="btn btn-primary">Detalles</button></a>
            <a href="" data-target="#modal-delete-{{$ing->idingreso}}" data-toggle="modal"><button class="btn btn-danger">Anular</button></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @include('compras.ingreso.modal')   
    @endforeach
    </table>
```

Vista crear

```
{!!Form::open(array('url'=>'compras/ingreso','method'=>'POST','autocomplete'=>'off'))!!}
            {{Form::token()}}
<div class="row">   
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6 col-dm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
              <label for="nombre">Proveedor</label>
             <select name="idproveedor" id="idproveedor" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
              @foreach($personas as $persona)
              <option value="{{$persona->idpersona}}">{{$persona->nombre}}</option>
              @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-dm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
            <label>Tipo de Comprobante</label>
            <select name="tipo_comprobante" class="form-control">
                <option value="Factura"> Factura </option>
                <option value="Boleta"> Boleta </option>
                <option value="Ticket"> Ticket </option>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-dm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="serie_comprobante">Serie Comprobante</label>
            <input type="text" name="serie_comprobante" readonly value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Serie de comprobante...">
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-dm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="numero_comprobante">Numero de Comprobante</label>
                <input type="text" name="numero_comprobante" required readonly value= "{{$iingreso}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Numero de comprobante...">
        </div>
    </div>  

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-dm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="anticipo">Anticipo</label>
                <input type="text" name="anticipo" required value="{{old('anticipo')}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Valor anticipo...">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="row">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-body">

<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-dm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">    
    <label>Articulo</label>
    <select name="pidaarticulo" id="pidaarticulo" class="form-control selectpicker"  data-live-search="true">
        @foreach($articulos as $articulo)
        <option value="{{$articulo->idarticulo}}">{{$articulo->articulo}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-dm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cantidad">Cantidad</label>
        <input type="number" name="pcantidad" id="pcantidad" class="form-control" placeholder="Cantidad">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-dm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="precio_compra">Precio de Compra</label>
        <input type="number" name="pprecio_compra" id="pprecio_compra" class="form-control" placeholder="precio de compra">
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-dm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="precio_venta">Precio de venta</label>
        <input type="number" name="pprecio_venta" id="pprecio_venta" class="form-control" placeholder="precio de venta">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-dm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="impuesto">impuesto</label>
            <select name="impuesto" id="piimpuesto" class="form-control">
            @foreach($impuestos as $impuesto)
            <option value= "{{$impuesto->porcentaje}}">{{$impuesto->descripccion}}</option>
            @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-dm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"  id="bt_agregar" onclick="agregar()">Agregar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-dm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="detalles" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
            <thead style="background-color:#caf5a9">
            <th>Opcciones</th>
            <th>Articulo</th>
            <th>Cantidad</th>
            <th>impuesto</th>
            <th>Precio Compra</th>
            <th>Precio Venta</th>
            <th>Subtotal</th>
        </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th><h4 id="total">$/. 0.00</h4></th>
            </tfoot>
        <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-dm-6 col-xs-12" id="guardar">
                    <div class="form-group">
                <input name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" type="hidden"></input>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary"  type="submit">Guardar</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="reset">Cancelar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        {!!Form::close()!!}  
         @push ('scripts')
        <script>
        var total=0;
        cont=0;
        total=0;
        subtotal=[];
        $("#guardar").hide();

function agregar()
        {
            idarticulo=$("#pidaarticulo").val();
            articulo=$("#pidaarticulo option:selected").text();
            cantidad=$("#pcantidad").val();
            impuesto=$("#piimpuesto option:selected").val(); 
            precio_compra=$("#pprecio_compra").val();
            precio_venta=$("#pprecio_venta").val();
              if (idarticulo!="" && cantidad!="" && cantidad>0 && precio_compra!="" && precio_venta!="")
        {
        subtotal[cont]=(cantidad*precio_compra);
        total=total+subtotal[cont];
        var fila='<tr class="selected" id="fila'+cont+'"><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="eliminar('+cont+');">X</button></td><td><input type="hidden" name="idarticulo[]"  value="'+idarticulo+'">'+articulo+'</td><td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" readonly value="'+cantidad+'"></td><td><input name="impuesto[]" readonly value="'+impuesto+'"></td><td><input type="number" name="precio_compra[]" readonly value="'+precio_compra+'"></td><td><input type="number"name="precio_venta[]" readonly value="'+precio_venta+'"></td><td>'+subtotal[cont]+'</td></tr>';
        cont++;
        evaluar();
        limpiar();
            $('#total').html("$/ " + total);
          $('#detalles').append(fila);

        }
    else
    {
        alert("Error al ingresar el detalle del articulo, revise los datos del articulo");
    }
        }


    function limpiar()
             {
                $("#pcantidad").val("");
                $("#pprecio_compra").val("");
                $("#pprecio_venta").val("");
             }

            function evaluar()
                {
                var indice = document.getElementById('idproveedor').selectedIndex
                    if(total>0)
                    {
                        if(indice=0)
                        {
                            alert("Debe seleccionar un cliente")
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("#guardar").show();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#guardar").hide();
                    }   
                }

    function eliminar(index){
    total=total-subtotal[index];
    $('#total').html("$/. "+total);
    $('#fila'+index).remove();
    evaluar();
        }


</script>
```

lo que tengo para hacerlo con eloquent es dos modelos relacionados de muchos a muchos por una tabla intermedia. Los probe por medio de tinker y me funcionan la pero no se como hacerlo en un controlador para el index y store.

Tabla intermedia

```
Schema::create('ingreso_articulo', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('articulo_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('articulo_id')->references('id')->on('productos');
            $table->integer('ingreso_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('ingreso_id')->references('id')->on('ingresos');
            $table->integer('cantidad');
            $table->decimal('precio_compra', 11, 2);
            $table->decimal('precio_venta', 11, 2);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Modelo Articulo

```
public function ingresos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ingreso','ingreso_articulo', 'articulo_id', 'ingreso_id')
        ->withPivot('articulo_id', 'ingreso_id', 'cantidad','precio_compra', 'precio_venta')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Modelo Ingreso

```
public function articulos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Articulo','ingreso_producto', 'ingreso_id', 'articulo_id')
        ->withPivot('articulo_id', 'ingreso_id', 'cantidad','precio_compra', 'precio_venta')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Agradeceria mucho su ayuda estoy estancado aqui en esta parte.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿cuál es el formulario?

Comment: Hola ya edite la pregunta y agregue el formulario.